# Angular undefined dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my code, I have a dropdown where a user can select an element. The user also can type in it and the dropdown will filter the elements and bring the element the user wants. The code works and dropdown does the filtering. But whenever the page first opens, inside the dropdown, `undefined` is written when it's supposed to be clear. Even though there is stuff in the dropdown. Here is my code. How can I fix that?
[image]

HTML:

```
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="25" class="pr-4">
                            <mat-label>Ürün</mat-label>
                            <input type="text" required matInput [(ngModel)]="product" name="product"
                            (input)="onProductSearchChange($event.target.value)" [matAutocomplete]="autoProductId">
                        <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #autoProductId="matAutocomplete"
                            [displayWith]="displayProduct.bind(this)">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let prm of productList" [value]="prm">
                                {{prm?.StockIntegrationCode +'  '+ prm?.ProductName}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-autocomplete>
                        </mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
productList: IProduct[];
  product: IProduct = {};
  constructor(
    private _stockService: StockService,
  ) { 
    

    _stockService.onProductsChanged.subscribe(
      (response: IProduct[]) => {
          this.productList = response;
      }
  );
  }
onProductSearchChange(search: string) {
  let filterValue = (search as any).toLocaleLowerCase("tr");
  if (
      this._stockService.products &&
      this._stockService.products.length > 0
  ) {
      this.productList = this._stockService.products.filter(
          (x) =>
              x.StockIntegrationCode.indexOf(filterValue) >= 0 ||
              (x.ProductName as any)
                  .toLocaleLowerCase("tr")
                  .indexOf(filterValue) >= 0
      );
  }
  if (!search) {
      this.product = null;
      this.productList = this._stockService.products;
  }
}

displayProduct(product: IProduct): string | undefined {
  return product
      ? product.StockIntegrationCode + " - " + product.ProductName
      : "";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try to declare ngModel value without initialize

```
 product: IProduct ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the bind() function strangely in your template. According to the [example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/mayoojongqq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts) from the Angular [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) you should be binding to `displayWidth` like this,

```
[displayWidth]="displayProduct"
```